# Angular 2 - if condition getting true for all values

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement

I have been stuck at a point, my `if` condition is returning true for all conditions, I am checking that a value is greater or not.

Code:

```
 hideAmountModal() {
    var self = this;
    self.home_delivery_charge = self.storeService.fetchHomedeliveryData(self.shopId);
    self.home_delivery_charge.subscribe((res: any) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (self.deliveryData.delivery_charge > res[i].amount) {
          self.check_delivery_charge = true;
          console.log('Deliverycharge',self.deliveryData.delivery_charge,'result',res[i].amount);
          console.log('deliver charge is greater',self.check_delivery_charge);
        }
        else if (self.deliveryData.delivery_charge < res[i].amount){
            self.check_delivery_charge = false;
        }
      }
    })
    self.DeliveryChargeValue = true
    self.selectAmountModal.hide();
  }
```

From the console what I get is below:

[image]

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Check if typeof res[i].amount and self.deliveryData.delivery_charge is number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting both values to number type

```
if (parseInt(self.deliveryData.delivery_charge) > parseInt(res[i].amount)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` condition from:

```
if (self.deliveryData.delivery_charge > res[i].amount)
```

To this:

```
if (Number(self.deliveryData.delivery_charge) > Number(res[i].amount))
```

Doing this, you would be explicitly `type-casting` your input type into number.

**Remember:** You'll get `NaN` (Not-a-Number) if your input can't be converted to number type.

In case you don't want this behavior you could always use `parseInt` which uses Javascript's `Number()` function under-the-hood as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364498/5349542).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because you are not handling the `equal` case, which you should include on the `else if`. Can you check that the values that you are comparing are numbers? This is probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You `console.log` only value when is true

Try add `console.log` here :

```
else if(self.deliveryData.delivery_charge < res[i].amount) {
  self.check_delivery_charge = false;
}
```